# Cross compiling nginx-1.0.11

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, archlinux

I want to know how to cross compile nginx-1.0.11.

I have already tried : --with-cc option
but it is giving me an error : checking for C compiler ... found but is not working

./configure: error: C compiler arm-linux-gcc is not found

--with-cc-opt is also not working.
I tried to change compiler manually too(by changing a Makefile).

I have already install arm-linux-gcc and its working fine with openssl(It successfully cross compiled openssl. so problem is not with arm-linux compiler).

Any help will be highly appreciated ..
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Should be targetted at unix.stackexchange.com (probably)

Comment: have you installed cross compiler? if you don't have 'arm-linux-gcc' then you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer. nginx has it's own non-autoconf configuration system which currently doesn't support cross compilation.

Either hack or avoid the configuration system, or wait until nginx adds support for cross compilation.

See http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,220607 where the issue has been recently discussed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran ./configure for my ia32 Linux host, and built it (to make sure it worked), then 
1) deleted all object files, 
2) edited objs/Makefile to change the value of CC, add include paths for my compiler and library paths for my linker
3) copied some header files from /usr/include to a local directory

There is a problem in that if /usr/include is in the search path, it is searched before the header files for my compiler.  This became a problem when x86 assembler instructions were pulled into the definition of htonl().

An alternative is to hack conf/cc/gcc to add an option and do configurations there, includeing supporting a shell variable of CROSS.  I haven't done that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered settng up QEMU - http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page and a lightweight image from linaro - http://www.linaro.org/. I have not tested this approach, but i can tell you that I have successfully compiled and running nginx on my Pandaboard ARM v7a.

Comment: Sounds like you are suggesting doing the build on a system compatible with the target.

Comment: Exactly, i find at times it is just easier instead of setting up cross-compilers, cross-compiling system libraries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully cross-compiled nginx by first creating a config on my desktop machine (./configure --without-pcre --without-http_rewrite_module), then just editing the 'cc' command in /objs/Makefile to point to the correct gcc. The Makefile the configure produces is incredibly simple. Just make sure you have all your environment variables set properly as well (CC, LD, LIBS, etc)

Comment: I didn't have the time to bother with Yocto yet and as rewrite module is not currently a requirement for me, this was a very nice workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just build v 1.4.7 this way

```
./configure --with-ld-opt=-L/path/to/libfolder \
   --with-cc-opt=-I/path/to/include  --prefix=./nginx
make CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
make install
```

--prefix nginx installs everithing in ./nginx and one just need to move created nginx folder on device but has to start server  from relative path.

```
./nginx/sbin/nginx
```

Comment: Were you going to say something?

Comment: What does the -L and -I mean in front of the path?

Comment: @trigster for gcc compiler I am using is flag where lib files are searched for. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options